# Core Data Multiple Threads - View Controller Not Updating

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to use Core Data in an app I'm working on; in the app delegate this code kicks off the import of data from a downloaded JSON file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //setup app window, etc.

    BECDRefreshOperation *loadData = [[BECDRefreshOperation alloc] initWithStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];

    [queue addOperation:loadData]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue

    return YES;

}
```

BECDRefreshOperation is a subclass of NSOperation that runs the import. It creates its own managed object context in order to separate the main one from the background process.

```
- (id) initWithStoreCoordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)storeCoordinator{
    if (![super init]) return nil;
    [self setPersistentStoreCoord:storeCoordinator];
    return self;
}

- (void) main{
    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoord];

    //import the data from JSON

}
```

The actual import works and updates the data store; however, the table view controller which uses an NSFetchedResultsController does not update. The table view controller is the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and contains all of the delegate methods.

On the second run of the app, the table view controller displays correctly because the data was previously loaded into the store; any updates made in the import do not refresh, however.

I have read the [Core Data Concurrency](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) guidelines from Apple multiple times as well as searched many times on Google and SO for the answer. I believe it lies in using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, but I have tried to do this in many different places in both the app delegate and the table view controller by registering for the save notification and calling a method to merge changes, and none of what I have tried works. [Cocoa is my GF's implementation](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/) is one of the ways I have tried to adapt in order to do this.

The table view controller is passed the app delegate's managedObjectContext when it is created.

I have run this without multithreading and the code to import into the data store and display in the table view controller works, but of course it freezes the UI while importing the data.

It's pretty obvious I'm doing something wrong here; any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update** 
I added some NSLog statements and break points to see if the two managedObjectContexts were indeed pointing to the same memory address and it seems that they are, while the background MOC is at a different address. The notification code seems like it should work and update the main MOC, but thus far it is not.

```
2012-06-25 21:48:02.669 BE_CoreData[18113:13403] beerListViewController.managedObjectContext = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x94233d0>
2012-06-25 21:48:02.671 BE_CoreData[18113:13403] appDelegate.managedObjectContext = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x94233d0>
2012-06-25 21:48:02.722 BE_CoreData[18113:15003] backgroundMOC = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7b301b0>
```

**Update 2** After additional troubleshooting it appears the NSFetchedController delegate methods are not firing. Here's the code for the NSFetchedResultsController and its delegate.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Beer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"beertitle" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"beertitle"
                                                   cacheName:@"BeerTable"];
    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Also here is the code for changeCell which is called when a cell needs updating:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Beer *beer = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = beer.beertitle;

    if (beer.beerthumb != nil){
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:beer.beerthumb]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
    else {
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://beersandears.net/images/missing.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }

}
```

Finally the fetchBeers method is called by viewDidLoad to actually perform the fetch.

```
- (void)fetchBeers{

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
}
```

**Update 3**

Testing to ensure the fetch occurs first. It does, but not by much (this was run on a 4S).

```
2012-06-28 20:47:37.214 BE_CoreData[3559:907] Fetch called
2012-06-28 20:47:37.281 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] Import started
2012-06-28 20:47:37.285 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] backgroundMOC = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1f03f050>
2012-06-28 20:47:39.124 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] call contextDidSave
2012-06-28 20:47:40.926 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] call contextDidSave
2012-06-28 20:47:42.071 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] call contextDidSave
2012-06-28 20:47:45.551 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] call contextDidSave
2012-06-28 20:47:45.554 BE_CoreData[3559:1103] Finished refresh operation
```

Instead of starting with a blank SQLlite store, I seeded a SQLlite store and ran through the same process. The seed loads correctly when it starts up, but the changes since the seed do not appear immediately in the table view. If you scroll to the spot where a row should be added before it's loaded (and it's not there), even after the import finishes it does not appear. However, scroll away and come back and the added row appears. It seems that when the database is empty it has nothing to scroll to and therefore doesn't add anything. With the seed it eventually adds them in but not in the way I've seen the core data stores work with an animated insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your context on the main thread is the same for app delegate and the view controller, it is just a design decision where you perform the merge.

The merge itself is pretty straightforward.

1. Register for NSManagedObjectContextDidSave notification.
2. Launch the background op.
3. Save on the background thread.
4. Merge the context in the observer method on main thread.

Here is the sample code how you perform the merge:

```
// Whatever method you registered as an observer to NSManagedObjectContextDidSave
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
       [self.managedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

And note, you actually have to save on the background thread for the notification to fire.

Comment: I did check to make sure the notifications and the method were firing; the import process calls context save a few times. I think I am going to have to triple check the delegate context and the table view context are the same context.

Comment: Okay so in the app delegate I allocate the table view controller, set its managedObjectContext property to the app delegate's, (`BeerListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext`), and use the table view controller's managedObjectContext (`self.managedObjectContext`) throughout the table view controller. I register for the notification in app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with the selector set to `contextDidSave:`. `contextDidSave:` is the exact code above, but no response from the view controller to the import. The data appears on the second run, however.

Comment: I added more information above about how the managed object context for the table view controller and the app delegate do share the same memory address while the background MOC is at a different memory address.

Comment: Can you please check if the data becomes available in the MOC on the main thread after merge. Then we know if we can throw NSFetchedResultsController out of the equation and focus on the MOC itself.

Comment: Yes I'll take a look tonight.

Comment: So good news; I made a fetch request from the table view controller after the import completed just to write the names of the beers into the database and it looks like they're all there. The fetch request used the table view's managedObjectContext, which we've previously established is the same memory address as the delegate's managedObjectContext. Looks like the NSFetchedResultsController is somehow at fault?

Comment: And you said above that you have tested this by writing those changes directly into the tableview controller's MOC and then NSFetchedResultsController worked? Could you double-check it? Try in the contextDidSave method to insert an instance of a managed object into tableview controller's MOC and see if NSFetchedResultsController's delegate method is triggered.

Comment: Yes, this all works when it is on a single thread. When it is all in one thread I believe the NSFetchedResultsController performs its initial fetch after the import is completed. I will investigate further.

Comment: It looks like the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods are not being triggered in the table view controller. Will add code for the delegate methods above, but I believe this is mostly Apple code.

Comment: NSFetchResultsController delegate methods are triggered only for changes that take place _after_ initial fetch. Make sure you perform your fetch first and then make the changes.

Comment: The fetch is done at the end of viewDidLoad in the table view controller. The table view controller is allocated, initialized, and put into a navigation controller. That navigation controller is added to a tab bar controller. All of this occurs before the import is called in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I'll put some log statements in to see exactly what is occurring when but the fetch should be happening before the import (I think).

Comment: See update 3 above; the NSFetchedResultsController fetch does occur before the import begins, but I also found some other unusual behavior.

Comment: For the benefit of debugging, can you try inserting a new object into managed object context in -contextDidSave: where you do the merge. I want to make sure that the NSFetchedResultsController does not only see the merge but does not see manual inserts either.

Comment: I did that a day or two ago and it did not see the manual inserts. I suppose it's worth checking again with a seeded database since I was using a blank one at the time. Even so, I think it will still behave the same.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to share a simplified Xcode project to illustrate the issue? I would gladly take a look.

Comment: Yes I can; to be honest the project isn't much more than this so far. I'll put it together hopefully tonight.

Comment: Here's where you can find the zipped project. I have been doing some experimenting with it, so it's not the neatest (commented code and such).

Key classes are BECDAppDelegate, BeerListViewController, BECDRefreshOperation.

http://scottwoliver.com/coredata/BE_CoreData.zip

Comment: Still strange... I put some log statements in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate didChangeObject method and according to them the inserts and updates are being done to the NSFetchedResultsController, but they do not show up in the tableview.

Comment: FIXED! For some reason I had declared tableview as a property and synthesized it even though tableview is a property of the UITableViewController subclass automatically. Removing the property and synthesize fixed it. Thank you for all your help!